# Throw unauthorized exception to be caught by UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute

Tags: exception, asp.net-core

I have setup UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute in asp.netcore website and it works fine.

I'm now trying to manually throw an error and I would like UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute to catch it automatically but not as a 500 but as a 401 !

What type of exception should I throw?

If it's not possible, I guess I will have to create my custom middleware. In that case, how do I redirect from it in case I have this exception?

Comment: Every uncaught exception is treated as 500 which means internal server error. When you want 401 code, just use the `return Unauthorized();` helper method from your action

Comment: @Tseng This is just not practical at all, it means I need to catch try every single call to my api at the controller level... isn't there a better way?

Comment: You can write a middleware or a filter, which catches the exception and transform it into a Unauthorized response (its basically an `StatusCodeResult` object, which implements `IActionResult`, see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/StatusCodeResult.cs). 401 means unauthorized, when the user is not logged in/authenticated.  But using exceptions here is kind of an abuse of the whole thing. Exception are for... exceptional things. a user thats not logged in or doesn't have permission or a specific action **isn't exceptional** but expected

Comment: Stuff you expect should be handled or passed back as results, not as exceptions. Also see [Why Exceptions should be Exceptional](http://mattwarren.org/2016/12/20/Why-Exceptions-should-be-Exceptional/). As for the 401 see the [RFC-7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-4.1) on what 401 is supposed to mean:

Comment: In my case, it is unexpected, because it means that you are logged in in the website but not on the api, which shouldn't happen. Thanks for the answer, I was expecting a more convenient way of handling this.